# APEX- Passing the values of the page item from my page 1 on submit and using a procedure to display these values on screen in the page2

Tags: oracle-apex

In page 1 I have a region which has many page items.
On entering the values in these page items and on click of submit,
I need to get redirected to page 2 and display all the values on the page(Please note that I will not be having any pageitems in the page 2)
How can I use a procedure in page 2 and get all the values from page1.
PS: My region is as below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JjOe.png)

and i want my output to be as below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CQ4v.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In APEX you would do this using a branch. A branch is executed after the processing and is used to (conditionally) redirect to another page. If the target of the branch is another page in the same app there is the option to set the page items on the target page with page item values of the current page.

In your case, I'd create the same page items on page 2 and then set the values in the branch. For example if you have P1_RELEASE_DEPENDENCY on page 1 then create a P2_RELEASE_DEPENDENCY on page 2 and set the value in the branch. Same for any other page items.

Suppose you have a region with static content on page 2 to display the values that were passed in the branch, then you could use the following source

```
My release dependency is &P1_RELEASE_DEPENDENCY.
```

The "&<PAGE_ITEM>." notation can be used in html only, not in pl/sql.

This is the clean way of handling this functionality. You currently don't have page items on page 2 but I would add those, just for displaying the values.

Comment: I have edited my question to have the expected details in the page 2.  How should i achieve this? i need to pass all the values from page 1 and need to display much more details in page 2 using the value. How can i create my procedure to capture all the region values and display them?

Comment: Updated the answer. You don't need a procedure for this.